# Getting a call to undefined method in laravel when doing events

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm getting this error when I do a post and it hits my event

> Call to undefined method App\Events\UpdateProductCount::__invoke()

This is my code

```
    public function create()
    {
        $product = Product::create([
            'name' => request('name'),
            'description' => request('description'),
        ]);

        dispatch(new UpdateProductCount($product));
    }
```

This is what I have in my UpdateProductCount event

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Events;

    use App\Models\Product;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

    class UpdateProductCount
    {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

        public Product $product;

        public function __construct(Product $product)
        {
            $this->product = $product;
        }

        public function broadcastOn()
        {
            return new PrivateChannel('product-count-update'.$this->product);
        }
    }
```

and this is what I have in my UpdateProductCountListener

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Listeners;

    use App\Events\UpdateProductCount;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

    class UpdateProductCountListener
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            
        }

        public function handle(UpdateProductCount $event)
        {
            dd($event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to run `composer update`

Comment: I tried that and I still got the same error

Comment: Your error message includes the line number and file causing the error, in addition to a full stack trace...

Answer (score 18):

After looking at my stack trace like @miken32 suggested it was complaining about this line

```
dispatch(new UpdateProductCount($product));
```

so I tried changing `dispatch` to `event`

```
// dispatch(new UpdateProductCount($product)); 
event(new UpdateProductCount($product));
```

and that worked.

Answer (score 11):

My problem was importing the wrong `Dispatchable` trait.

wrong:

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
```

correct:

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
```

Comment: **Thank You!** Such an easy thing to miss and had stumped me, you'd think the error message might see you're trying to `dispatch` something which is the wrong kind of `Dispatchable`.

Answer (score 0):

prob in your EventServicesProvider you must have:

```
UpdateProductCount::class => [
      UpdateProductCountListener::class,
]
```

Comment: In haste, actually had a similar issue, I pointed my Event to another event, instead of the listener.